# How to debug reactJS "Could not proxy request"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, fetch-api

I am attempting to deploy a pern app using this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJxUOOND5_A). At around 22:14 he talks about using a proxy to take out the 'localhost' in the fetch requests.

I have followed this exactly, resulting in this for the proxy;

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

and this for how I request:

```
const response = await fetch("/auth/is-verify", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: { token: localStorage.token }
})
```

This always gives me the error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /auth/is-verify from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

I have tried:

- deleted node modules and package-lock.json and reinstalled and restarted
- added a '/' to the proxy
- restarted computer between attempts
- used incognito mode (as there are no cookies/cache)
- navigating to the http://localhost:5000/auth/is-verify route directly (Works perfectly fine, with response text being retrieved from the server and displayed on a blank page as expected for direct route access)
- changing the proxy to the network location given when running npm start on the react app.
- using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

I have no clue how to test for causes further. All my research has led me too people saying to "make sure the server is up" and other general concerns, but these general solutions don't help this case.

Comment: Have you tried to change the `http://localhost:5000` to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to list that.  Is it perhaps some config thing? What usually breaks this system. was I meant to install anything the guide skipped over?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure my case is the same as yours, but I encountered a quite similar problem, and found a way to fix it for me, so maybe it will fix it for you and others as well :

my setup was I used wsl, and my back used a cygdrive shell (the reason being I needed it for another project with same IDE), and my front used the wsl shell. Both my front and my back were on the windows part of wsl.

After moving both on the linux part of wsl, my back started using the wsl shell as well, and this error disappeared.

My guess would be because of cygdrive the localhost meant something different for my front and my back, but I can't guarantee it.

Best of luck.